# scraping job url data from indeed using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm designing a web scraper that scrapes jobs from Indeed. I'm able to successfully scrape, job title, company, location, salary information. However, I'm having difficulty finding the job url for that specific job on Indeed so the user would be able to find more information and how to apply.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract(position, location, page):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={position}&l={location}&start={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    job_title = soup.find_all('table', class_='jobCard_mainContent')
    
    for item in job_title:
        title = item.find('h2').get_text()
        company = item.find('span', class_='companyName').get_text()
        location = item.find('div', class_='companyLocation').get_text()

        try:
            salary = item.find('div', class_='heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer').get_text()
        except:
            salary = 'none'
       
        job = {         
            'Title': title,
            'Company': company,
            'Location': location,
            'Salary': salary,
        }
        jobList.append(job)
    return
    
jobList = []

a = extract('swe', 'nyc', 0)
transform(a)
data = json.dumps(jobList, indent=2)
print(data)
```

Job search: 'swe', Location: 'nyc'

```
[
  {
    "Title": "newWebsite Developer and Social Media Video maker",
    "Company": "La Reserve",
    "Location": "New York, NY",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Entry Level Computer Programmer",
    "Company": "Revature",
    "Location": "New York, NY+9 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Entry Level Software Engineer",
    "Company": "Revature",
    "Location": "New York, NY+17 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Junior CSS/HTML Developer",
    "Company": "Revature",
    "Location": "New York, NY+8 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Front End Developer",
    "Company": "Underdog.io",
    "Location": "New York, NY",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "2022 Software Engineer",
    "Company": "Bloomberg",
    "Location": "New York, NY 10261",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Front End Developer (Entry level)",
    "Company": "Revature",
    "Location": "New York, NY+8 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Junior Software Developer",
    "Company": "Revature",
    "Location": "New York, NY+5 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Payments Software Engineer, Apple Pay",
    "Company": "Apple",
    "Location": "New York, NY+3 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Frontend React developer | In-house",
    "Company": "ManageGo",
    "Location": "Brooklyn, NY 11211",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Web Developer / HTML",
    "Company": "Phoenix Technology Partners",
    "Location": "New York, NY",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Junior Software Engineer",
    "Company": "TransPerfect",
    "Location": "New York, NY",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "new2022 Software Engineer Program - Full Time Opportunity",
    "Company": "JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A.",
    "Location": "New York, NY+76 locations",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "newSoftware Engineer I (Junior/Entry-level Backend Engineer)",
    "Company": "Boxed",
    "Location": "New York, NY+1 location",
    "Salary": "none"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Software Developer (Full-Time, Entry-Level)",
    "Company": "Accelerated Information Systems",
    "Location": "Hicksville, NY 11801",
    "Salary": "none"
  }
]
```

Comment: So this code actually working right?

Comment: Can you please show where the `url` that you mentioned should be gathered? Show us the html or the xpath will be helpful

Comment: correct, just having difficulty parsing the html for a job url since i'm using the json data in a different app, I would use the link so the user can find more information and possibly apply.

Comment: i updated the main code with the entire working file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a closer look at the website, I found this solution. As said in my comment, I moved one item up so that the URL is included in the class picked. The URL extension is given by `item['href]` and I just add that to the base URL.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.indeed.com'

def extract(position, location, page):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={position}&l={location}&start={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    job_title = soup.find_all('a', class_="tapItem")
    for item in job_title:
        title = item.find('h2').get_text()
        job_url = base_url + item['href']
        title = item.find('h2').get_text()
        company = item.find('span', class_='companyName').get_text()
        location = item.find('div', class_='companyLocation').get_text()

        try:
            salary = item.find('div', class_='heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer').get_text()
        except:
            salary = 'none'
       
        job = {         
            'Title': title,
            'Company': company,
            'Location': location,
            'Salary': salary,
            "Job Url": job_url
        }
        jobList.append(job)
    return
    
jobList = []

a = extract('swe', 'nyc', 0)
transform(a)
data = json.dumps(jobList, indent=2)
print(data)
```